# Microsoft Word - Deleting Format Marks

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

In the attached screenshot, you can see that there are many cells that are simply just too large for no reason, and I am unable to resize them.  They appear to have some hidden formatting marks and I'm assuming that these marks have something to do with my problem.

As an example, the line that says "OWNER AND MAILING ADDRESS" looks like it contains two lines when in reality there is only one line.  So if I only have enough text in that cell to span one line, there is still space below it and I want to get rid of the extra space.  Is this possible?  I wasn't sure if it had to do with these formatting marks or with style formatting or what.

Also, please note that this is not my Word file.  I do not encounter these problems when I am making my own document.

[image]

Comment: "OWNER AND MAILING ADDRESS" - it's actually 6 cells, it seems to be one as borders are white, but small round / square icon at the end of cells indicates that that's the end of the cell. Also there are some extra space below the texts, it may come from paragraph settings (space below) or table properties (table / cell options - cell margins)

Comment: Ohhhhhh.  Yeah it appear you are correct.  Not sure why they (it's a government form) would set it up this way, but it's good to know the solution.

Comment: I suppose they intended it to be filled by handwriting after printing,  so real structure is less important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "OWNER AND MAILING ADDRESS"  looks like it contains two lines when in reality there is only one line

it's actually 6 cells, it seems to be one as borders are white, but small round / square icon at the end of cells indicates that that's the end of the cell.

Also there are some extra space below the texts, it may come from

- paragraph settings (space below)
- table properties (table / cell options - cell margins)